# Running a shell script with a push button using Tinkerboard S GPIO pins

Tags: shell, gpio

I'm currently trying to figure out how to incorporate a push button into my shell script using the GPIO pins on a tinkerboard S. The purpose of the tinker board is to act as a HDMI video source. I have it running as a video source but need to include a button so I can cycle through different video files once pressed.

My shell script consists of this one line that plays a video and repeats it infinitely:

```
while true; do gst-play-1.0 video_loop.mp4; sleep 1; done
```

I want to be able to cycle through different MP4 files when the button is pressed. Something like this:

```
Play video_loop.mp4
if button is pressed play video_loop1.mp4
if pressed again play video_loop2.mp4
```

I've tried a few things but cant seem to get it to work, any help is appreciated.

Comment: The looping aspect can be easily achieved with two nested loops. Are you asking about that, or about how to interface with the button? Please [edit] to focus on one problem only.

Comment: Read about `gpio-keys` kernel module and how to use it.